# Xcode 10 iCloud Entitlement Value Mismatch Error for KVStore Identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, xcode10, entitlements

I have a project where we manually manage entitlements due to the fact that we deploy many different apps from the same codebase. We're facing a problem now where, after upgrading to XCode 10, we get an error stating

`Provisioning profile "<profile>" doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement. (in target '<target-name>')`

We use project variables to fill in the entitlement's value as it directs us to do in the Apple Documentation for enabling iCloud in your application as shown below:

`<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
<string>$(TeamIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>`

And, for reference, this is the value in our provisioning profile we're seeing this error for:

`<key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
<string><team-identifier>.*</string>`

NOTE 1: This works in Xcode 9.x and only recently stopped working after we upgraded to Xcode 10.

NOTE 2: When I print out the value for the `TeamIdentifierPrefix`, it's the same one the Provisioning Profile contains.

NOTE 3: When I hard code what the value for the `TeamIdentifierPrefix` should be (which I got from the provisioning profile), it works.

NOTE 4: May be obvious, but this works if I remove the iCloud entitlements from the entitlements file.

NOTE 5: We supply the path to each app's respective entitlements file under the Code Signing build settings.

I can't imagine there was a change in how project variables are resolved or anything like that, so I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas.